# Fabric JS canvas objects below remote image not selectable

Tags: fabricjs

I'm trying to setup FabricJS but canvas become unselectable below remote images.

I figured it out, that selection area is calculated before images are loaded and then canvas is "pushed" below images, so its objects becomes unselectable. This only occurs when you refresh page. When you enter new link everything is fine.

```
<body>

    <div class="product thumbnail">
        <a href="remoteimage">
            <img src="remoteimage" alt="1232g" />
            1232g
        </a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <canvas id="canvas-id"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(function() {
          var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas-id');

          // create a rectangle with angle=45
          var circle = new fabric.Circle({
            radius: 20, fill: 'red', left: 100, top: 100
          });
          var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
            width: 20, height: 30, fill: 'blue', left: 50, top: 50
          });

          canvas.add(circle, triangle);
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

How to setup FabricJS properly in this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are talking about

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var imgElement = document.getElementById('my-img');
var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  angle: 30,
  opacity: 0.85
});
canvas.add(imgInstance);
```

You can check the documentation here : http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1/ in the Images Section